# Matplot table, legend, stacked barplot issues

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working on a stacked barplot and, as you can see, it's got some issues:
[image]
1) How can I add alpha to the colors in the table? I tried adding `alpha=0.75` in `the_table` but it didn't do anything.
2) <s>How can I increase the height of the table rows to fit the text?</s>
3) <s>How can I move the '3/1' bar so that it's centered over the table column?</s>
4) <s>How can I move the legend so that it's centered above the graph?</s>
5) How can I fix the legend being cut off?

Here is the code I have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

res = (0, 21)
canc = (21, 0)
me = (37, 37)
ee = (4, 4)
sw = (16, 16)
te = (31, 31)
spec = (1, 1)
sys = (2, 2)
lm = (9, 9)

data = [res, canc, me, ee, sw, te, spec, sys, lm]
labels = ['Resolved', 'To be cancelled', 'Mech Eng', 'Elec Eng', 'Software', 'Test Eng', 'Specialty', 'Systems', 'LM Review']
dates = ('2/22', '3/1 (Projected)')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

index = np.arange(len(dates))
bar_width = 0.25
y_offset = np.array([0.0] * len(dates))

gray = plt.cm.gray(0.5)
yellow = plt.cm.hot(0.9)
green = plt.cm.Greens(0.5)
magenta = plt.cm.RdPu(0.5)
orange = plt.cm.Oranges(0.5)
purple = plt.cm.Purples(0.5)
greenblue = plt.cm.GnBu(0.4)
red = plt.cm.Reds(0.5)
blue = plt.cm.Blues(0.5)
colors = [gray, yellow, green, magenta, orange, purple, greenblue, red, blue]

cell_text = []
for row in range(len(data)):
    plt.bar(index, data[row], bar_width, bottom=y_offset, color=colors[row], alpha=0.75, align='center', label=labels[row])
    y_offset = y_offset + data[row]

colors = colors[::-1]
data.reverse()
labels.reverse()

the_table = plt.table(cellText=data, rowLabels=labels, rowColours=colors, alpha=0.1, colLabels=dates, loc='bottom', cellLoc='center')
the_table.scale(1, 1.6)

plt.ylabel('Open Items')

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2, bottom=0.35)

plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 130, 5))
ax.set_xlim(-0.5, 1.5)
plt.legend()

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles[::-1], labels[::-1], bbox_to_anchor=(1., 1.15), ncol=4)

plt.show()
```

EDIT: Found:
The solution to #2 & #3.
A workaround to #1, but would still like to be able to actually apply alpha rather than rigging the colors.
Got the legend where I want it, but now it's cut off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Adding alpha: You can use the alpha channel of the respective color. This is done by converting the color to rgba and then set the alpha of the tuple to the desired value.

```
alpha = 0.75
colors = ['gray', 'yellow', 'green']
cols=[]
for c in colors:
    col = list(matplotlib.colors.to_rgba(c))
    col[3] = alpha
    cols.append(col)
```

2) Center legend above graph: This is all a bit depending on the figure size, font size etc. so the ideal parameters need to be found by trial and error, but the idea can be to place the bounding box of the legend in the center of the axes (x=0.5) and on top of it (y=1.0) and specify the `loc` parameter to `'lower center'` which means that the bottom center of the legend should be at that point. making `y` a bit larger produces some padding between legend and axes.

This is the complete script, where I also adapted the figure size to let all of the plot fit into the canvas.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors

res = (0, 21)
canc = (21, 0)
me = (37, 37)
ee = (4, 4)
sw = (16, 16)
te = (31, 31)
spec = (1, 1)
sys = (2, 2)
lm = (9, 9)

data = [res, canc, me, ee, sw, te, spec, sys, lm]
labels = ['Resolved', 'To be cancelled', 'Mech Eng', 'Elec Eng', 'Software', 'Test Eng', 'Specialty', 'Systems', 'LM Review']
dates = ('2/22', '3/1 (Projected)')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6)) #<- set figure size large enough for data

index = np.arange(len(dates))
bar_width = 0.25
y_offset = np.array([0.0] * len(dates))

# set alpha to colors:
alpha = 0.75
colors = ['gray', 'yellow', 'green', 'magenta', 'orange', 'palevioletred', 'mediumspringgreen', 'red', 'blue']
cols=[]
for c in colors:
    col = list(matplotlib.colors.to_rgba(c))
    col[3] = alpha
    cols.append(col)
colors = cols[::-1]

cell_text = []
for row in range(len(data)):                              #colors need to be inverted here as well, don't they?
    plt.bar(index, data[row], bar_width, bottom=y_offset, color=colors[::-1][row], alpha=0.75, align='center', label=labels[row])
    y_offset = y_offset + data[row]


data.reverse()
labels.reverse()

the_table = plt.table(cellText=data, rowLabels=labels, rowColours=colors, alpha=0.1, colLabels=dates, loc='bottom', cellLoc='center')
the_table.scale(1, 1.6)

plt.ylabel('Open Items')

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.22, bottom=0.35, right=0.78, top=0.82) # <- allocate some spacing for legend on top and on right as well

plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 130, 5))
ax.set_xlim(-0.5, 1.5)
#plt.legend() <- remove, we only need one single legend defined below

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
# loc=8 means the bbox ccordinates define the lower center of the legend
# so placing it at x=0.5 ( horizontal center of the axes), y=1.02 (vertical top of the axes)
ax.legend(handles[::-1], labels[::-1], loc=8, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.02), ncol=4)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting an error though: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'to_rgba'`. Looks like I have version 1.5 installed and I guess `to_rgba` is version 2.0 only?

Comment: That could be. Does `matplotlib.colors.colorConverter.to_rgba(c)` work instead?

Comment: It does not. Trying to download and install 2.0 now.

Comment: That's strange, according to [the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.1/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.ColorConverter), even in matplotlib 1.4 there is a `matplotlib.colors.ColorConverter` with a `to_rgba` method.

Comment: Don't know why I'm getting that error then. But installing 2.0 fixed it. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh and just a heads-up, you're inverting the colors twice. It worked fine the way I did it, after setting the bar plots.