# Seaborn Plot- Add the frequency along the axis

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

**Plotting the feature details in comparison to the target variable**

```
# Read the data
data=pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sharmaroshan/Online-Shoppers-Purchasing-Intention/master/online_shoppers_intention.csv")
data.head()
```

Normal Plotting of Region in reference to the target variable:

```
sns.countplot(x='Region',hue='Revenue',data=data)
```

[image: Region vs Revenue]

Kindly help me to get the frequency table along the X-axis of the plot:

(Reference to the image below):
[image: sample]

Comment: what do you mean by frequency..could you elaborate some sample.. And i think you have to inidcate the structure of csv or an example will be welcome. And i suggest you to show your complete code..

Comment: Hi, I have attached the CSV (raw file) as a data, and it's a bivariate analysis between 2 features-- Region and Revenue. Using count plot I could obtain the general format. Inorder to obtain along with the counts in form of table (in the reference image) . Requesting for a code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42417458/matplot-table-legend-stacked-barplot-issues).

Comment: @Quang Hoang, thanks but I think it's kind of related to alpha

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplot table, legend, stacked barplot issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42417458/matplot-table-legend-stacked-barplot-issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to grab a table with 'seaborn'. I added a table with 'matplotlib' to create a graph.

```
df = data.loc[:,['Revenue','Region']]
df2 = df.groupby(['Revenue','Region'])['Revenue'].agg('count').to_frame('Count')
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
df3 = df2.pivot(values='Count', columns='Region', index='Revenue')
df3 = df3.rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
df3.set_index('Revenue',inplace=True)
df3
        1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
Revenue                                 
False   4009 948 2054 1007 266 693 642 378 425
True    771  188  349 175  52  112 119 56 86

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,3),dpi=144)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

n_rows = len(df3)
labels = df3.columns.values
width = 0.35

x = np.arange(len(labels))
y1 = df3.iloc[0]
y2 = df3.iloc[1]

ax.bar(x - width/2, y1, width, label='False')
ax.bar(x + width/2, y2, width, label='True')
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_xticklabels([])

ax.legend()
cell_text = [list(y1.values),list(y2.values)]

ax.table(cellText=cell_text, rowLabels=df3.index, colLabels=df3.columns, loc='bottom')

plt.title('Region wise session vs Revenue Generated')
plt.ylabel('Count')
ax.set_xlabel('Region')
ax.xaxis.set_label_coords(0.5, -0.25)

plt.show()
```

[image]